# JComboBox makes GUI disappear

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

As soon as I add

```
String[] possibleClasses = {"12", "11", "10", "9", "8", "7", "6", "5"};
JComboBox classes = new JComboBox(possibleClasses);
```

to any of my programms, no swing component whatsoever is displayed in the frame.
The only thing I get is an empy frame. Is there some secret to using JComboBox I am to stupid to findout about?

Comment: We're going to see more code to figure out what's going on.  Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: Are you also adding it to your JFrame?

Comment: how can i see weather you added the combo box in frame or not ?

Comment: For better help & sooner, consider posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: seems you missing `frame.add(classes);` in your code

Comment: You seem to be missing a bit of tutorial reading. Trying to make stuff up doesn't work. Let the tutorials show you how to do it.

Comment: There is no secret to using a JComboBox. All you have to do is read the JComboBox API where you will find a link titled "How to Use Combo Boxes" which takes you to the Swing tutorial and contains a working example.

Answer (score 2):

Simply creating a `JComboBox` is not enough to make your component appear in the `JFrame`, you need to *add* it to the container:

```
myJFrame.add(classes);
```